# Kotlin versus android java in terms of working on Dalvik VM

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I would like to know whether kotlin is the same as android java in terms of low level interactions. By this I mean that android java files are converted to dex files and then they can be run on Dalvik VM and what about kotlin files? Is it the same way or there is something else? And where can I find more information about this? May be some good book talks about it? Thank you.

Comment: Kotlin compiles to Java bytecode, and there are tons of resources about this if you google for it - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#what-does-kotlin-compile-down-to

Comment: @zsmb13 Okay, so they are almost the same in terms of this question?

Comment: Yes, you end up with .class files from both compilers, and then they compile down to .dex all the same.

Comment: @zsmb13 Can you please add your answer so that I could check it as the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kotlin compiles to Java bytecode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#what-does-kotlin-compile-down-to), and for the purposes of Android, the `.class` outputs of both of these compilers are transformed to `.dex` files in the same way, at that point in the process, their source languages are completely irrelevant.

[Here](https://youtu.be/CtZL_IjR5Ww?t=6m20s) is a part of a talk by Jake Wharton where he explains the intricacies of actually resolving references so that interop can work both ways between Java and Kotlin, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin is just compiled to Java's bytecode. For any "special" functions, like extensions or null-protection, Kotlin just injects some code. For example, with null-protection, the Kotlin code may look like:

```
fun setPackageName(pName: String) {
    //do something
}
```

While it compiles to:

```
public final void setPackageName(@NotNull String pName) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(pName, "setPackageName");
    //do something
}
```

If you have a variable in Kotlin, with a setter/getter:

```
var something: Something? = null
    get() {
        return field
    }
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

Kotlin will just convert the whole setup into a private member variable and some methods:

```
private Something something;

public Something getSomething() {
    return something;
}

public void setSomething(Something something) {
    this.something = something;
}
```

Obviously, this sett/getter is pretty useless, but it illustrates what Kotlin might do.

Basically, Kotlin just converts itself to Java at compile-time.